# I am getting following error while connecting to my database

Tags: php, mysql, internal-server-error

I am getting following error while connecting to my database:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@main-hosting.eu to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

php_error.log file:

```
[25-Feb-2017 09:45:09 UTC] PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.hostinger.in' (4 "Interrupted system call") in /home/u191892126/public_html/API/connect.php on line 8
```

My php file:

```
<?php
$servername = "mysql.hostinger.in";//var deceleration I tried "localhost" too
$username = "u1918921**_root";
$password = "*********";
$dbname = "u191892126_acare";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors','On'); ` enable the errors and see the proper error

Comment: the error describes the problem ! you have to contact your hosting provider :)

Comment: Thank you for your help Pranav MS and Hassan Ahmed. And yes I tried contacting the email id, it showed an error email does not exists

Comment: @PranavMS The OP posted the contents of the http servers error log file which makes much more sense to look at than trying to inject error messages blindly in html markup.

Comment: call the support and ask them to restart the services again and try .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a server's error tried it again(it took 4 hours) and everything was working fine.